# How to set a initial value for a text field in a form? This value is generated from a javascript function. How can i define the event without botton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<body onload="onload();">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" id="test"  title="TEST" />
</body>
```

This is the javascript to generate a value for the text field.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function onload() 
{ 
 var a=0;
 a++:
 document.getElementById("test").value=a;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What does "How can i define the event without botton?" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a body onload event,

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

or a jquery onload event:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 document.getElementById("myFrame").addEventListener("load", test);
 function test() {
  document.getElementById("doi").value = "Iframe is loaded.";
  alert(document.getElementById("doi").value);
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you use one of this functions?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var a=0;
   a++;
   document.getElementById("test").value=a;
});
```

OR

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var a=0;
   a++;
   document.getElementById("test").value=a;
});
```

Both of them start when the page is loaded.

By the way... in this case `a` will always be 1